# Retrieve results having custom video duration from youtude data api 3

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

So youtube data api 3 has video duration parameter : short (less than 4 min), medium (4 to 20 mins) and long(more than 20 minutes)

any ideas how i can retrieve results having custom video duration lets say i would like to get results for my query string of video duration of 3 to 6 minutes only

thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is currently not possible. There's a related request [here](http://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=5263&q=youtube%20duration&colspec=API%20ID%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20Stars%20Summary).